# Use of unassigned local variable error for a assigned string

Tags: c#, variables

So, I'm beginner in C# and I really don't know why I'm getting "Use of unassigned local variable error" for the variable "name". I have this simple code that asks for a name, and if it's not Bob or Alice, it shows a message.

```
using System;

namespace exercise2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string name;
            int i = 0;
            while (i == 0)
            {
                Console.Write("What is your name?\n>>> ");
                name = Console.ReadLine();
                if ((name == "Alice") || (name == "Bob"))
                {
                    i = 1;
                    Console.Clear();
                }
                else
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("You're not Alice or Bob.");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    i = 0;
                    Console.Clear();
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Good Morning, " + name); //"name" is unassigned
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that it's not a stupid question.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because compiler cannot "see" the evaluation on `while()` statement will definitely be `true` and `name` will be assigned in the `while` block for the first time.

Change your

```
string name;
```

into

```
string name = ""; //or string.Empty
```

Although as human we can read easily that the while block is going to be executed for the first time:

```
string name; //unassigned
int i = 0;
while (i == 0) //will enter
{
    Console.Write("What is your name?\n>>> ");
    name = Console.ReadLine(); //name will definitely be assigned here
    ... something else
}
Console.WriteLine("Good Morning, " + name); //compiler cannot "see" that the while loop will definitely be entered and name will be assigned. Therefore, "name" is unassigned
```

The *compiler cannot see that*, thus giving you the error.

Alternatively, you could also change the `while` block to `do-while` to force the compiler to see that the `name` will be assigned (Credit goes to [Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152602/lee)):

```
string name; //unassigned
int i = 0;
do //will enter
{ 
    Console.Write("What is your name?\n>>> ");
    name = Console.ReadLine(); //name will definitely be assigned here
    ... something else
} while (i == 0);
Console.WriteLine("Good Morning, " + name); //should be OK now
```

Comment: Changing the loop into a `do while` should also work.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. What I don't understand is, the only way to leave the while block isn't only when it's true, which means that name will be assigned? If that makes sense

Comment: @lfsando maybe the easiest way to understand this is: the compiler will see ur name variable as unassigned and then go line by line to check if it is used before assigned or not. However, if the compiler sees a while condition, it *does not evaluate the condition at all*, it *assumes* that it could go wrong and you do not enter the while loop. Based on that, the compiler thinks that the name *could be* unassigned and thus gives you error. When you change into do-while, the compiler does the same thing, but it definitely can see that your name is assigned. Maybe that's how we can understand it.

Comment: @Ian Thanks ! That makes sense

Answer (score 1):

The name variable is unassigned at some point in the branching process where it could be used.  You could assign it a default value, but refactoring it is a better solution.

Move the name variable inside the while loop to avoid reassignment.  (putting it inside the while loop technically isn't reassignment of the same variable, because when it loops again, a new variable is created and the previous set value is unavailable).

Move the following two lines into the true portion of the conditional:

```
Console.WriteLine("Good Morning, " + name);

Console.ReadKey();

static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int i = 0; //this should really be bool, 
        //because all you're doing is using 0 for repeat and 1 for stop. 
        while (i == 0)
        {
            Console.Write("What is your name?\n>>> ");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            if ((name == "Alice") || (name == "Bob"))
            {
                i = 1;
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Good Morning, " + name); //"name" is unassigned
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else
            {

                Console.WriteLine("You're not Alice or Bob.");
                Console.ReadKey();
                i = 0;
                Console.Clear();
            }

        }

    }
}
```